# How to make a list of JSON objects into a JSON file in Python and join multiple ones?

Tags: python, json, api

I am working with an API that returns the following format:

```
{
    "count": 900,
    "next": "api/?data&page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": 
        [{json object 1}, {json object 2}, {...}]
}
```

Problem is that I want to retrieve all "results" from all pages, and save that into one json file.

I'm thinking of a while loop that keeps making requests to the API and aggregating the resulting "results" into one variable, until the "next" value is null.

Something like

```
while json1["next"] != null:
    r = request.get(apiURL, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    raw_data = r.json()["results"]

    final_data.update(raw_data)
```

I tried it but since r.json()["results"] is a list I don't know how to handle the different formats and transform that into a JSON file

When trying to do `final_data.update(raw_data)` it gives me an error saying:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Or when trying `json.loads(raw_data)` it gives me:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes, or bytearray, not list"
```

Comment: Intresting!....

Comment: What do you mean with "since r.json()["results"] is a list I don't know how to handle the different formats"? You should be able to save a list to a JSON file without issue.

Comment: Is There Any Error You are Getting When Saving The JSON? The Error Would Help Understanding The Issue!

Comment: @DMalan When trying to do for example json.loads(raw_data), I get the error: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes, or bytearray, not list".

Comment: Can You Share More Code?

Comment: If you're trying to save the data to a file, you need to use `json.dumps`, not `json.loads`.

Comment: @GanimeDewer @DMalan There's not much else to the code. The problem is that raw_data is a list of json objects, and it does not let me aggregate that into a json when doing `final_data.update(raw_data)`

Comment: "When trying to do final_data.update(raw_data) it gives me an error saying:" This problem is because of `final_data`, not because of `raw_data`. It also has nothing to do with JSON. "I'm thinking of a while loop that keeps making requests to the API and aggregating the resulting "results" into one variable" - since the "results" will be lists, your plan was to aggregate them **into a list**, right? So. Does Python's `list` have an `update` method? Apparently not, right? Do you know how to merge the contents of lists? If not, that is the real question here - please see the linked duplicates.

Comment: "Or when trying json.loads(raw_data)" Well, yes, because that **makes no sense**. Loading is when you take JSON data and create objects (`dict`s and `list`s) in your Python program. You already have a list, and you want to make JSON data from it; that is saving, not loading. That is a separate issue; we generally want one question per post here, but I added the reference duplicate for this task as well.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I understand now, sorry for the confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON file is a text file. To save your `raw_data`, which is a list, in a text file, you need to encode it using `json.dumps()`:

```
import json

with open('output.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    raw_data_as_string = json.dumps(raw_data)
    f.write(raw_data_as_string)
```

To aggregate the results from different pages, your `final_data` can be a list, created **before** you iterate the pages, and then you can `final_data.extend(raw_data)` in a loop, where `raw_data` contains results from a single page.

After that you `json.dumps(final_data)` as shown earlier.